# how to use timer on button click in java

Tags: java, timer, actionlistener

Hello I want to print text in a `textarea` once I click on button from `array`. Elements should be printed after a specific time interval.

I have done the following but not getting desired output:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    final int[] arr = new int[10];
    Timer t = new Timer();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        final int j = i;
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                jTextArea1.append("" + arr[j] + "\n");
                if (j == 0) {
                    cancel();
                }

            }
        }, 1000, 1000);
    }
}
```

Desired output: Elements should be printed after a specific time interval 
Current output: Continuously prints 0

Comment: What is the desired output? What is the output of your code?

Comment: Desired output :  Elements should be printed after a specific time interval

Comment: output of code is : continuously printing 0

Comment: Can you example a bit of what you'd like to see as output? Are you trying to see the values incrementing? If so you are trying to do this with an array that hasn't been populated with any values. Your arr array doesn't contain anything so when you are doing arr[j] you are saying get me the nth element of an empty array.

Comment: having UI with one button and TextArea, I want to print data from array which contain say n elements, in textarea; each element after a specific time intervel. this should have to be done once I click button from UI.

Comment: Your array is empty mate. You are declaring the array but you never assign a value to the array so it would definitely print 0's

Comment: I understood that point dear and thanks for that but point is that it is continuously printing 0's. I want to print only elements in array not repeatedly

Comment: Better not call people 'dear', it could be interpreted as a derigotory tone. Unless of course you intended that, in that case, please be nice (-:

Comment: Yes I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over the array and adding a TimerTask for each element. Why not do it the other way round? If you are on Java 5 or higher you can use the more advanced ScheduledExecutorService. I also changed the code to request a single execution after 1000 millis instead of a scheduleAtFixedRate which repeats the execution.

```
final int[] arr = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
Runnable task = new Runnable () {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            jTextArea1.append(String.format("%s%n", arr[j]));
        }
    } 
}, 1000);
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
ScheduledFuture<?> future = scheduler.schedule(task, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

Comment: `you can use the more advanced ScheduledExecutorService.` - Swing components should be updated on the Event Dispatch Thread. You should use a Swing Timer or a SwingWorker.

Comment: Guess you are right. I wasn't focused on the fact that this is probably within a Swing context.